# Spring security invalid login handling

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am new to Spring security, so I am trying to use Spring MVC to handling invalid login, but ended up with Page Not Found 404

In my security-context.xml, i have this `AuthenticationProvider` handling all the authentication login, so just basically checking the user's account and password, but for some reasons it keeps saying the `authentication-failure-url` is not found 404 whenever there's an invalid login attempt.

```xml
  <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider ref="AuthenticationProvider"/>
  </security:authentication-manager>

  <bean id="preAuthenticationFilter"
      class="authentication.PreAuthenticationFilter"
      p:authenticationManager-ref="authenticationManager" />

  <security:http auto-config="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/member/**" access="MEMBER" requires-channel="https"/>
    <security:form-login login-page="/login"
                         username-parameter="email"
                         password-parameter="password"
                         default-target-url="/member/"
                         authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />
    <security:custom-filter position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="preAuthenticationFilter" />
  </security:http>
```

But I do have a corresponding controller listens to that url pattern for handling invalid login.

```
@Controller
public class LoginController
{
    @RequestMapping(value = "/loginfailed", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginError(ModelMap model)
    {     
         model.addAttribute("error", "true");
         return "login";
    }
}
```

*******UPDATE**************

At some points my `AuthenticationProvider` validates the user and throw an exception (I don't know if that matters) whenever the user has a bad credential

```
@Component
public class AuthenticationProvider{
    private User validateUser(String userName, String password)
    {
        try{
            //authenticate user's info
            .......
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
        {
             throw new BadCredentialsException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `method = RequestMethod.GET` work?

Comment: No...I have tried both GET and POST

Comment: Seems to me that it's not Spring Security issue, but rather MVC configuration - does simple POST / GET request to `/loginfailed` return 200 status?

Comment: no i got 302 back from j_spring_security_check and then a 404 not found /loginfailed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*(As follow-up to comments.)* 302 statu from j_spring_security_check and `BadCredentialsException` are both correct. It looks like your controller isn't registered at all. Do you have in mind that annotating bean with `@Controller` isn't enough to make it work? [Quoting documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-controller):

> You can define annotated controller beans explicitly, using a standard
>   Spring bean definition in the dispatcher's context. However, the
>   `@Controller` stereotype also allows for autodetection, aligned with
>   Spring general support for detecting component classes in the
>   classpath and auto-registering bean definitions for them.
>
> To enable autodetection of such annotated controllers, you add
>   component scanning to your configuration. Use the spring-context
>   schema as shown in the following XML snippet:
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
>     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>     xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
>     xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
>     xsi:schemaLocation="
>         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
>         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
>         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
>         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
>
>     <context:component-scan base-package="com.example"/>
>
>     <!-- ... -->
>
> </beans>
> ```

(assuming `LoginController` is in com.example package).

Simple bean declaration can be use instead of component scanning:

```
<bean class="com.example.LoginController" />
```